# hibernate sql query not mapping booleans correctly?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

Running the following via any SQL client

```
SELECT FALSE, TRUE;
```

returns

```
f, t
```

However this SQL query:

```
SQLQuery qry = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT FALSE, TRUE;");
Object[] result = (Object[]) qry.uniqueResult();
```

returns an Object array containing two Boolean objects:

```
[false, false]
```

I'm using postgres 9.0-801.jdbc4 with hibernate.

How do I return the appropriate boolean value via a hibernate sql query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change definition for your boolean property in mapping file:

```
<property name="someBoolean" column="SOME_COLUMN" type="true_false"></property>
```

or if you using annotations add this one:

```
@Type(type="true_false")
```

This should help because by default hibernate maps boolean property as BIT but not as CHAR(1) and I think thats why you have such problem. (look at [hibernate mapping types](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-basictypes)).

**EDIT:**

If you need to select boolean using SQLQuery (as separated value not as a field of entity) you can use such approach:

```
SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT FALSE a, TRUE b;");
q.addScalar("a", new TrueFalseType());
q.addScalar("b", new TrueFalseType());

Object[] result = (Object[]) q.uniqueResult();
```

As you see in this case you need explicitly define the type of fetched value so hibernate can convert it correctly. I tested this approach in MySQL and all is working (except that in my case I specified type *BooleanType()* because MySQL works with booleans as 1/0).

Hibernate use three boolean formats:

1) "Y/N" -> CHAR(1) ansi sql type -> "yes_no" hibernate type -> YesNoType class;

2) "T/F" -> CHAR(1) -> "true_false" hibernate type -> TrueFalseType class;

3) "1/0" -> BIT ansi sql type -> "boolean" hibernate type -> BooleanType class;

So you need to choose correct type for your DB (as I understood and as I wrote in my example you should use *TrueFalseType*).

Comment: there are no mappings, this is a SQLQuery. I am selecting a boolean from the database, and getting booleans back, however they are the wrong value.

Comment: Ok. I misunderstood you. I edited my unsfer and now I hope it will help you.